# EXEC dynamic SQL built from query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have done some searching and have come up a little short of meeting my need.

I am limited by coding standards that prevent me from using NVARCHAR(MAX) or VARCHAR(MAX) which is my pain point.

I need to create a dynamic SQL statement that most likely will be longer than 8000 characters. The reason this happens is because of a huge CASE WHEN statement that is being asked to be used. My approach was to insert each CASE WHEN as a record into a table. Then I use XML PATH('') in a dynamic SQL statement to create another dynamic SQL statement.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTest (
ID INT
,Data VARCHAR(50)
,Data2 VARCHAR(50)
,Flag INT
)

CREATE TABLE #TempCase (
ID INT
,CaseS VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TempCase (
ID
,CaseS
)
VALUES
(1,'CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN Data ELSE Data2 END')
,(2,'CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN ID ELSE 0 END')

INSERT INTO #TempTest (
ID
,Data
,Data2
,Flag
)
VALUES
(1,'Hobo','Jim',1)
,(2,'Hobo Again','Jane',2)

EXEC('SELECT TOP 1 ''SELECT '' + STUFF((SELECT N'', '' + CaseS
    FROM #TempCase TC
    ORDER BY TC.ID
    FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''), 1, 2, N'''') + '' FROM #TempCase''
FROM #TempCase TC
GROUP BY TC.ID')
```

The result of this EXEC statement is -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN Data ELSE Data2 END, CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN ID ELSE 0 END FROM #TempCase
```

The result of the query is the dynamic SQL that I have to run. I tried to nest my current EXEC statement into another EXEC statement but this only created two datasets with the same result. Doing some searching the way most people handle this is by setting the initial EXEC result to a VARCHAR(MAX) and assigning that to a second EXEC statement, which I cannot do because of my company's coding standards.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`, in that case the `@sql` can be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: The limits are there for a reason - using dynamic SQL is bad as it exposes you to sql injection, and is *very* hard to maintain and debug if you get a single character wrong. A dynamic SQL statement greater than 8000 characters is *very* bad as maintaining it becomes almost impossible. Performance will probably be very bad as well, as the optimizer will have a hard time coming up with a plan for such a complex query. Why not create one or more views with the CASE statements and only SELECT the fields that you want? Or break the big query into multiple queries that you combine with UNION ALL ?

Comment: Because I can't use NVARCHAR(MAX) - @sql would still have to be defined as NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: I understand the issues of SQL injection however the process doesn't have a user front end so not really an issue. I already am selecting only the fields I need however based on what is returned in the record determines the output hence the need for the CASE WHEN statements. The information comes from a different server therefore I would like to only query the data once.

Comment: The optimizer creates two execution plans. Storing a basic run that includes the use of the dynamic sql and then a secondary cached example for each time the dynamic sql is executed. If the hash of the dynamic sql matches an already cached version the optimizer uses the cached version. So I don't this performance will be an issue. By putting the CASE WHEN statements in a table I can add controls that allow specific pieces to run or not run. This allows my process to grow and change with the needs of the report making it easy to maintain.

Comment: but after concatenating via FOR XML, you are using nvarchar(max)  as the sql type when converting the value extracted from the xml output, so even if you could do exec(exec) it would still be against the coding standards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have access to create temp tables and you already have the logic to put the various CASE statements in a table (and a few other assumptions which may or may not be valid but are nonetheless implied yet lacking explicit description here), how about the following approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTest
  (
       ID    INT,
       Data  VARCHAR(50),
       Data2 VARCHAR(50),
       Flag  INT
  )

CREATE TABLE #TempCase
  (
       ID    INT,
       CaseS VARCHAR(50),
       CaseSDataType VARCHAR(20),
       HasProcessed BIT DEFAULT(0)
  )

INSERT INTO #TempCase
            (ID,
             CaseS,
             CaseSDataType)
     VALUES (1,
             'CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN Data ELSE Data2 END',
             'VARCHAR(50)'),
            (2,
             'CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN ID ELSE 0 END',
             'VARCHAR(50)')

INSERT INTO #TempTest
            (ID,
             Data,
             Data2,
             Flag)
     VALUES (1,
             'Hobo',
             'Jim',
             1),
            (2,
             'Hobo Again',
             'Jane',
             2) 

CREATE TABLE #Computed ( ID INT )
INSERT INTO #Computed ( ID ) SELECT ID FROM #TempTest

DECLARE @caseID INT
DECLARE @caseSQL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @colSQL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @updateSQL VARCHAR(255)
WHILE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM #TempCase WHERE HasProcessed = 0 )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 
        @caseID = ID, 
        @caseSQL = REPLACE(REPLACE('ALTER TABLE #TempTest ADD CaseStmt{id} AS ({stmt})', '{id}', CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)), '{stmt}', CaseS),
        @colSQL = REPLACE(REPLACE('ALTER TABLE #Computed ADD CaseStmt{id} {datatype}', '{id}', CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)), '{datatype}', CaseSDataType),
        @updateSQL = REPLACE('UPDATE t2 SET t2.CaseStmt{id} = t1.CaseStmt{id} FROM #TempTest t1 INNER JOIN #Computed t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID', '{id}', ID)
    FROM #TempCase 
    WHERE HasProcessed = 0

    -- Add the columns
    EXEC(@caseSQL)
    EXEC(@colSQL)

    -- Update the column
    EXEC(@updateSQL)

    -- Next
    UPDATE #TempCase
       SET HasProcessed = 1
    WHERE ID = @caseID
END

-- Return your results (all of #Computed)
SELECT * FROM #Computed
```

Effectively, the structure of #Computed becomes the result as if the various CASE statements were all chained together in a single SELECT statement.

We could shortcut the creation of the computed column by simply poking the CASE statement directly into the UPDATE sql, but that would have required, potentially, some manipulations of the CASE statements to ensure the table prefixes were correct.

Comment: I thought about this however the fact that my data is coming from another server increases running time as the number of CASE WHEN statements increases. This is why I was trying to query with all of the statements at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Building dynamic SQL that way you are exposed to SQL Injection!

Anyway you could insert result of first `EXEC` to temp table and execute it:

```
CREATE TABLE #final(result VARCHAR(8000));

INSERT INTO #final(result)
EXEC(
'SELECT TOP 1 ''SELECT '' + STUFF((SELECT N'', '' + CaseS
    FROM #TempCase TC
    ORDER BY TC.ID
    FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''), 1, 2, N'''') 
        + '' FROM #TempTest''   
FROM #TempCase TC
GROUP BY TC.ID');

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @sql = result
FROM #final;

EXEC(@sql);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443908)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ Hobo ║    0 ║
║ Jane ║    2 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: But if the result of the SQL is longer than 8000 characters the string would be cut off.